# removeAll vs empty an array with [] in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I want to throw away the data in my observablearray everytime I get data from my server.

What is the difference in functionality between

```
self.myArray([]);
```

vs

```
self.myArray.removeAll();
```

Comment: The first one creates a new observable and all subscriptions to the old one are lost.

Comment: @DCoder sorry I made a typo... please have a look again.

Comment: You could read the source code of Knockout to see how it's implemented. They both clear the array, the only noticeable difference is what they return - the first option returns the observable itself, the second returns the old values.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From the end result point of view there is no difference between the two call, so you will end up with `myArray` containing no elements.

However there is one small difference (if you don't care about the different return values):

```
self.myArray([]);
```

will **replace the underlying array instance** with a newly created empty array.

While the

```
self.myArray.removeAll();
```

will remove all the items from the underlying array but **it will keep the array instance**.

So if you have multiple `ko.observableArray` using the same underlaying array you can see the difference between the two calls:

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LCQQH/)

Comment: From a memory perspective, is `removeAll()` better? e.g. will it release all the memory from anything holding onto the array?